# Is there CAD table on pokerstars?

Tags: online

I have deposit CAD money on pokerstars and I have set my default and prefered currency to CAD. However, I can't join anygame because it's say I have to convert my money to USD, Pound, EURO. I fear I will get conversion fees if I do. More over, I have read on the internet that I might get the conversion fees twice...

Once to convert my money to currency of the table and another time when I went to cash out and get back my money in CAD. 
Really, this doesn't sound appealing to at all...

Isn't there CAD table on pokerstars?

Comment: I have asked the support. We will see if they answer and what they answer.

Answer (score 1):

No they currently don't, here is their answer.

> Thank you very much for your email and for allowing us to assist you
>   with your doubts.
>
> **We do not have tables in CAD,** however this is not an issue that will affect you, please find the details below.
>
> PokerStars currently offers games and tournaments in USD, EUR and GBP
>   and we may offer games in other currencies in the future. Besides USD
>   and EUR, we also offer the option to hold your account balance in GBP
>   or CAD and to make any of these four currencies your 'Preferred
>   Currency'.
>
> In order to make it easy to play games in currencies other than your
>   'Preferred Currency', PokerStars has enabled features which will allow
>   you to seamlessly enter and leave games, without ANY conversion fees.
>
> For example, if CAD is your Preferred Currency, and you wish to play a
>   game or tournament which takes EUR currency, you can buy-in directly
>   from your CAD account, without needing to convert funds first. Then
>   you can have any winnings placed directly into your account in CAD,
>   automatically. There is no conversion margin for these transactions.
>
> You can enable automatic conversions from the 'Settings' app in the
>   PokerStars lobby. Once in 'Settings', click on 'Global' then 'Multi
>   Currency' and enable the following two options and click 'Apply
>   Changes':
>
> - Convert currencies automatically, without confirmation.
> - Credit funds in my preferred currency when leaving a game.
>
> With these options selected, your buy-ins will be converted
>   automatically at the current conversion rates, and any money that you
>   take from the tables or win in tournaments will be automatically
>   converted back to your 'Preferred Currency'.
>
> For more details on how Multi-Currency works, please take a look at
>   the following web page:
>
> http://www.pokerstars.com/poker/real-money/multi-currency/
>
> in particular, please review the Multi-Currency FAQ:
>
> http://www.pokerstars.com/poker/real-money/multi-currency/#faqbelow
>
> To avoid the margin fee being charged on your deposit and cashout
>   transactions, we would advise you to submit the request from your CAD
>   bankroll account. The exchange rate margin will only be charged if the
>   bankroll currency is different to the processing currency.
>
> Please note that leaving a table, tournament deregistration, real
>   money transfers, intra-accounts transfers (between bankrolls) or any
>   other game related conversion, you will not be charged the margin fee.